# If we define own constructor then how does java initialize instance variables to their default value

Tags: java, default-value, default-constructor

Java assigns default values to instance variables using default constructor. But if we define our own constructor then how does java give default values (because  when we write our constructor then, then default constructor is not added).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ***Java assigns default values to instance variables using default constructor.***

No, not really. It automatically assigns default values to all members prior to executing *any* constructor.

> ***But if we define our own constructor then how does java give default values (because when we write our constructor then, then default constructor is not added).***

It still assigns default values to all members.

```
class Test {

    int i;
    Object ref;

    Test() {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(ref);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
null
```

Comment: Means it's not necessary that values are given in default constructor?

Comment: Just to add, if you want to see this place a breakpoint in the constructor, before statements in constructors are executed, eclispe debugger will initialize run through all the member variables. Good answer +1

Comment: values given in default constructor are to override the default values provided by JVM, like say as the code given above, you may want i to be 20 by default but JVM will always initialize it to 0, so in constructor you will mark i = 20;

Comment: Means JVM assigns default values through technique other than "Default Constructor"

Comment: @swdeveloper, yes. The default values are initialized automatically and has nothing to do with the default constructor.

Comment: Thanks @aioobe actually i studied an article about that at http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initialization.html, but had some confusion that I might have not understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens when an object is created using `new`; see [JLS 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

1. Space for the object is allocated on the heap, and the object's size and class are associated with the object.
2. All fields of the object are set to the default value; i.e. `null` or reference types, and zero or false for primitive types.
3. The argument expressions for the `super` or `this` arguments (if any) are evaluated, and the constructor chain is called recursively.
4. If they haven't already been evaluated (via `this` chaining), any instance field initializers and any initializer blocks for this class are evaluated/executed in order.
5. The rest of the constructor body (if any) is executed to complete the object initialization.

The same procedure is used whether there is an explicitly declared constructor, or a default constructor.  A default constructor is simply a short-hand for a constructor that just calls `super()`.

So ....

> Java assigns default values to instance variables using default constructor.

Actually, the default values are assigned before that, and (indeed) initializers, etc are executed *before* an (empty) default constructor is executed.

The default constructor is not responsible for doing default initialization.  So the fact that it is not invoked doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

aioobe's answer is right. I just want to say why/how it is that way:

Independent of whether you have a default or own constructors, the java compiler constructs **instance initialization "methods"** for each one (called void **`<init>`**, with the constructor's parameters - if you want to look into decompiled byte-code).

The structure of each `<init>` "method" is:

- An invocation of another constructor
- Instance variable initializers (your instance variable initializers, as well as instance initializers)
- The constructor body.

Further details can be found in [the JLS and JVMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), as well as [in this nice introduction](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DefaultValue {

    private boolean BOOLEAN;

    private byte BYTE;

    private  short SHORT;

    private  int INT ;

    private  long LONG;

    private  float FLOAT;

    private  double DOUBLE;

    private  char CHAR;

    private  Object OBJECT;

    public DefaultValue() {
        System.out.println("I did nothing!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DefaultValue dv = new DefaultValue();
        System.out.println(dv.BOOLEAN);
        System.out.println(dv.BYTE);
        System.out.println(dv.SHORT);
        System.out.println(dv.INT);
        System.out.println(dv.LONG);
        System.out.println(dv.FLOAT);
        System.out.println(dv.DOUBLE);
        System.out.println(dv.CHAR);
        System.out.println(dv.OBJECT);
    }

}
```

I rewrite the default constructor. Though I did nothing in the constructor, the variables are assigned.